# Monospaced fantasy fonts

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, monospace

I'm looking for Monospaced fonts based on fantasy-world languages like Aurabesh from Starwars or any of the Tolkien languages, but I'm having trouble finding any that are Monospaced. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: Monospace fonts are traditionally associated with Typewriter emulation and Programming. I don't think that's usually at the front of mind when creating a Fantasy or Scifi font.

Comment: you could try finding something that looks-a-like at [dafont](http://dafont.com)

Comment: @Jongware yeah, I haven't had any luck finding any, so I presume they are rare. I was hoping someone might know of some.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions to get you started:

[Rune](http://www.dafont.com/rune.font)

[image: rune monospace font]

[Exodite](http://www.dafont.com/exodite.font)

[image: exodite font]

[Magzetician](http://www.dafont.com/magzetician.font)

[image: Magzeticianfont]

[Comic Runes](http://www.dafont.com/comicrunes.font) (!!!)

[image: comic rune font]

[Nyctographic](http://www.dafont.com/nyctographic.font)

[image: nyctographic font]

---

**And.. oh well, why not have a look at the whole category, there's so many that could work for you!**

http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=705&fpp=100

It will be hard to find any elvish kind of font that is monospace/fixed width because it's kind of script-like. But you shouldn't have too much issues finding some runic style font or something more "alien" like!

Maybe the keywords used for the fonts in the links above can help you find better ones too. The screenshots above are not all perfect monospace.

Comment: It looks like the only one on the list that has all the chars the same width is Magzetician but I had to add the "Monospaced" PANOSE code/tag/whatever/thing. I was able to tweak Nyctographic a little also in font forge to get it to work.

Comment: @xdhmoore Sorry if there's not many fonts there that were really good for you. Unfortunately these are considered "dingbats" and don't have all characters indeed; but some paid versions do, so maybe it's worth checking. At least you seem to know enough to tweak some of them yourself. I admit that isn't something I looked for but I did wondered if the missing characters could be an issue for you :/ I see you're doing more than design with this, you're actually going to use this for "real" text! Interesting! An extra keyword for your search could be "enochian" but maybe it's not complete either

Comment: Lol, so, my actual use is to use it for some hobby writing in vim.  Nothing important. nothting that will ever be printed or used elsewhere, so I'm just looking for 26 characters. i've been using a tweaked FreeMono font with a vim keymap setting from [a-zA-Z] to runic characters. Yeah, i've been able to figure out how to tweak them a little.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290912/how-do-i-get-gnu-unifont-or-free-mono-working-on-gvim-windows/10308297#10308297

Answer (score 0):

What about http://www.cssfontstack.com/Copperplate this not exactly monospaced but looking clear enough and fantasy in my opinion.

Comment: Could you include a sample image of the font?

Comment: I"m looking for "fantasy" as in Runes or  other alphabets